# is there a big difference between extending ListViewActivity and just creating the listview by id?

Tags: android, android-listview

I was extending `ListViewActivity` and everything worked fine. I needed an actionbar (using support library) so I extended `ActionBarActivity` and then switched my code up to find the listview and set the list adapter and now I constantly get a NPE and it points to my adapter. I checked the values and they are not null? Here is my code

```
public class ViewMovies extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    Bookmarks bookmark;
    ListView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.viewmovie);
        int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Movie> movielist = extras.getParcelableArrayList("movielist");
        movies = movielist;     
        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(this, R.layout.viewmovie,
                movielist, maxMemory);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
        view.setOnItemClickListener(ViewMovies.this);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }
```

I know `movielist` is not null so I am not sure the error, the only difference I can think of is that I am using `setAdapter()` instead of `setListAdapter()`, but I don't think that is the issue.

error

```
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112): Process: com.example.moviesearch, PID: 11112
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moviesearch/com.example.moviesearch.ViewMovies}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at com.example.moviesearch.ViewMovies.onCreate(ViewMovies.java:39)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-13 15:11:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(11112):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.viewmovie);
```

You haven't set a layout. Even if you had, it wouldn't have a view with an `R.layout` id. Therefore this `findViewById()` call returns `null` and attempting to call a method on `null` later causes the NPE.

Change this to something like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);
```

Comment: ah thanks for the fast answer, looks like I need to take a break missing something so simple lol.